# PQ - Function.InvokeAfter() - real delay

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Trying to calculate real delay between InvokeAfter-function's executions.

Function is supposed to fire five times a second

```
index  delay now
0      0     18:47:33
1      0     18:47:33
2      0     18:47:33
3      0     18:47:33
4      0     18:47:33
5      1     18:47:34
6      1     18:47:34
7      1     18:47:34
8      1     18:47:34
9      1     18:47:34
10     2     18:47:35
11     2     18:47:35
12     2     18:47:35
13     2     18:47:35
14     2     18:47:35
...
```

But I get this

[image]

Column **real_delay** is a difference between this row and previous

## CODE

```
let
    t = Table.FromList({0..19}, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
    delay = Table.AddColumn(t, "delay", each Number.IntegerDivide([Column1], 5)),
    InvokeAfter = Table.AddColumn(delay, "InvokeTimeNow", each Function.InvokeAfter(
        ()=>DateTime.Time(DateTime.LocalNow()), #duration(0,0,0,[delay]))
    ),
    real_delay = Table.AddColumn(InvokeAfter, "real_delay", each try InvokeAfter{[Column1=[Column1]-1]}[InvokeTimeNow]-[InvokeTimeNow] otherwise "-")
in
    real_delay
```

***What's wrong with code? Or maybe with InvokeAfter-function???***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 times a second means you should be waiting (second / 5) = 0.2 fractional seconds each invocation.

If you run this code:

```
let
    t = Table.FromList({0..19}, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
    delay = Table.AddColumn(t, "delay", each 0.2),
    InvokeAfter = Table.AddColumn(delay, "InvokeTimeNow", each Function.InvokeAfter(
        ()=>DateTime.Time(DateTime.LocalNow()), #duration(0,0,0,[delay]))
    ),
    real_delay = Table.AddColumn(InvokeAfter, "real_delay", each try InvokeAfter{[Column1=[Column1]-1]}[InvokeTimeNow]-[InvokeTimeNow] otherwise "-")
in
    real_delay
```

you'll see the function was invoked about 5 times per second.

Comment: here is your result
Sorry, could not insert an image...
Anyway, the result is at least strange

Answer (score 0):

---

## == SOLUTION ==

---

---

Here is my own solution. A surprising one, I think...

[image]

## NEW CODE

```
let
    threads=5,
    t = Table.FromList({0..19}, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
    delay = Table.AddColumn(t, "delay", each if Number.Mod([Column1], threads)=0 and [Column1]>0 then 1 else 0),
    InvokeAfter = Table.AddColumn(delay, "InvokeTimeNow", each Function.InvokeAfter(()=>DateTime.Time(DateTime.LocalNow()), #duration(0,0,0,[delay]))),
    real_delay = Table.AddColumn(InvokeAfter, "real_delay", each try InvokeAfter{[Column1=[Column1]-1]}[InvokeTimeNow]-[InvokeTimeNow] otherwise "-")
in
    real_delay
```

The original idea was the multithreading parsing. And since there were some limits for simultaneous connections, I had to adapt.

I thought there is a "null-zero-start" moment, after which function is invoked - the moment, when cell is calculated (all cells almost at the same time). And second parameter means a delay after this start point. But it appears to accumulate all the delays. Very strange behaviour, imho...

So I solved the problem, but still do not understand why =)

Comment: @Carl would you comment?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to explain what's very strange about this behavior, I think I understand everything that's going on. This updated code is delaying by 1 second on call #6, #11, etc,, so the net result is that 80% of your calls delay be one second, and 20% of your calls takes a total time of one second, which makes sense.

Comment: I expected InvokeAfter to fire asynchronously. I.e. when counter takes next cell, it instantly fires something like JS setTimeout which in its turn fires inner function after delay.
Now I understand - next cell is treated ONLY after previous accomplish

Comment: Aha. Right, we don't have any asynchronous functions (but many values are computed lazily, on demand)